# Check if an algorithm is provided by FIPS module

Tags: c, openssl, fips

I am using Openssl-3 with the FIPS provider and want to confirm that it's being used for different algorithms. One way to do this is listed in the Openssl 3 wiki: https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/OpenSSL_3.0#Confirming_that_an_algorithm_is_being_provided_by_the_FIPS_module

It needs some changes to address the API change in Openssl 3 and I wrote a small C script to try it out.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <openssl/provider.h>
#include <lopenssl/evp.h>

int main(void)
{
    EVP_MD_CTX * mdctx;
    md = EVP_get_digestbyname("sha1");
    mdctx = EVP_MD_CTX_new();
    EVP_DigestInit_ex2(mdctx,md,NULL);
    printf(OSSL_PROVIDER_get0_name(EVP_MD_get0_provider(EVP_MD_CTX_get0_md(mdctx))));
}
```

I expect the name of the module as output which in this case should be FIPS. But I am getting a segmentation fault.

I tried debugging in GDB to understand the problem and I am getting a seg fault at EVP_MD_get0_provider(md = 0x0). Here is the definition for EVP_MD_get0_provider: https://github.com/openssl/openssl/blob/master/crypto/evp/evp_lib.c#L793

So it looks like the argument passed in the EVP_MD_get0_provider is NULL which is leading to the segfault. The argument passed is the return of EVP_MD_CTX_get0_md(ctx) which is defined here: https://github.com/openssl/openssl/blob/master/crypto/evp/evp_lib.c#L1021

If my ctx is NULL then the return will be NULL but since I have initialized ctx, it should not be NULL.

Please help me understand why am I getting a seg fault here and how can I fix it.

**Edit**:

Made some changes suggested by Matt@:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <openssl/provider.h>
#include <openssl/evp.h>

int main(void)
{
    EVP_MD_CTX * mdctx;
    mdctx = EVP_MD_CTX_new();
    printf("EVP_DigestInit_ex(mdctx,EVP_sha256(),NULL): %d\n", EVP_DigestInit_ex(mdctx,EVP_sha256(),NULL));
    printf("OSSL_PROVIDER_available: %d\n",OSSL_PROVIDER_available(NULL,"fips"));
    printf(OSSL_PROVIDER_get0_name(EVP_MD_get0_provider(EVP_MD_CTX_get0_md(mdctx))));

}
```

Here is the Config file:

```
config_diagnostics = 1
openssl_conf = openssl_init
.include /Openssl/build/ssl/fipsmodule.cnf
[openssl_init]
providers = provider_sect
[provider_sect]
fips = fips_sect
base = base_sect
[base_sect]
activate = 1
```

Output when hooked to GDB:

```
EVP_DigestInit_ex(mdctx,EVP_sha256(),NULL): 1
OSSL_PROVIDER_available: 1

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
ossl_provider_name (prov=0x0) at crypto/provider_core.c:1490
1490        return prov->name;
```

I am able to verify that the FIPS provider is loaded and also the error is now different, it fails on `EVP_MD_get0_provider`.

Comment: Most likely the `EVP_DigestInit_ex2` call is failing. You don't check the return value to confirm that it is successful. If this init fails then the MD will not be properly set in the mdctx and so it is not surprising that `EVP_MD_CTX_get0_md()` fails. If `EVP_DigestInit_ex2` is failing it is probably because there are no suitable providers available. You don't show how you load your providers (presumably via config). You should show your config file. Also check the output from `OSSL_PROVIDER_available(NULL, "fips")` to confirm the fips provider has loaded successfully.

Comment: Thanks @Matt. I modified the code to check for the return value of init call and also verify that FIPS provider has loaded successfully.

Answer (score 1):

Openssl-3 wiki also talks about fetching algorithms https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/OpenSSL_3.0#Fetching_algorithms_and_property_queries from a specific provider.

```
int main(void)
{
    EVP_MD_CTX * mdctx;
    EVP_MD * sha256;
    mdctx = EVP_MD_CTX_new();
    sha256 = EVP_MD_fetch(NULL,"SHA-256","fips=yes");
    if (sha256 == NULL)
        exit(1);
    printf("EVP_DigestInit_ex(mdctx,sha256,NULL): %d\n", EVP_DigestInit_ex(mdctx,sha256,NULL));
    printf("OSSL_PROVIDER_available: %d\n",OSSL_PROVIDER_available(NULL,"fips"));
    printf(OSSL_PROVIDER_get0_name(EVP_MD_get0_provider(EVP_MD_CTX_get0_md(mdctx))));
}
```

This gives me the expected output:

```
EVP_DigestInit_ex(mdctx,EVP_sha256(),NULL): 1
OSSL_PROVIDER_available: 1
fips%
```